# Would you buy a Neptune

Tags: wallet, client, buy-bitcoins, e-wallet

I really value your opinion. My question is in yuor personal opinion would you purchase and wait for a neptune from KNC or do you think I can get something better for my value. This will be my first mning machine and I want to it be a good investment.

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking only a very small percentage of people have actually made a profit mining (by profit, I mean made more bitcoins than you would get than just buying them outright).

At almost every point during bitcoins existence the way to acquire the most bitcoins would be to buy them.